# Google Play Console rejects app over login credentials

Tags: google-play, google-play-console

My app got rejected from Google Play because it has "Invalid or incomplete login credentials" and they are asking for a demo account.

There are only two methods for signing into my app: using your Google/Facebook account. I don't want to provide my personal social accounts to Google for this so how do I resolve this issue and let the reviewer still gain access to the app? Do I have to provide my personal credentials for this to work?

Comment: Hi @Tom, I am facing the same issue. How did you solve this issue? I really appreciate any help you can provide.

Answer (score 0):

Just create a new demo account for login , and this will solve problem .

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).